# If I update a file of type svg then how can I get the svg string out of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, image-upload

I need the data in this format after selecting an SVG icon from any file upload.

```
<svg
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <path
    fill-rule="evenodd"
    clip-rule="evenodd"
    d="M5 21C3.89543 21 3 20.1046 3 19V5C3 3.89543 3.89543 3 5 3H19C20.1046 3 21 3.89543 21 5V19C21 20.1046 20.1046 21 19 21H5ZM6 18V6H18V18H15V9H12V18H6Z"
    fill="currentColor"
  />
</svg>
```

Please take help of this website: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

here we can upload any SVG and under the markup section, we can see its HTML version.

I also want to implement something similar.

Comment: [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it solved:

```
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        console.log("onload: ", evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `file.text()`

```js
// Simulate a file u would get from a file input.
const file = new File(['<svg>content</svg>'], 'ico.svg')

// Read the content
file.text().then(svgText => {
  console.log(svgText)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var stringData = document.getElementById('my-svg').outerHTML;
```

Comment: after uploading a file all I get is the File object, how can get the SVG HTML content.